# Debug an ASP.Net User Control on Server

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Have an existing asp.net Web Forms project that on my own computer I can debug ok but on a server it's installed on a user control is causing an issue.  If I use Developer Tools I can see that a button on the user control creates the response "Input string in an incorrect format".  But this is all I get so trying to debug which field or value it's talking about is impossible, I don't get the issue on my own machine so I need some way to be able to drill down the detail of this problem.  If it was a page then I would get the full blown error with the Stack Trace and finding this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how easy it would be to set up a debugger.  If you were the IIS admin and were on an intranet with your users, you could host on your personal computer and have the user connect to your host.  When they visit your page and errors should cause your debugger to run.

I think a better option, though, is to implement some sort of logging mechanism.  This is a more practical and sustainable solution.  If you need help writing a logging class, post back here.

Comment: I can logon to the server but its a client server so not able to debug that way infortunately.  The Application Log shows the error but again no further detail like the stack trace.

Can I implement a logging class easily as the project is quite large and don't want to spend too much time changing all forms/controls acordingly.

Comment: Well, you would just have to write the logging class and implement it only where you think the error is occurring.  In best practices, yea you should implement it everywhere in your application but for this situation, you could just use it in the user control

Answer (score 0):

Check all datetime and string conversion. And also the web.config file on server.

If it is datetime conversion error, then change the cultureinfo.